# Find absolute parent of a section in a multilevel menu

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, menu, multi-level

I have a multilevel menu in my website and the following database table structure:

- section_id
- parent_id
- section_name
- section_permalink

I know it's not the best table design :|

What I want to do is to get the absolute parent (the section with parent_id = 0) of a section in this menu.

To retrieve the whole tree I use this function:

```
function generate_sections_select($parent, $level, $selected) {
    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE parent_id = :parent_id AND deleted = '0'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':parent_id', $parent, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($selected == $row['section_id']) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['section_id']."' selected>".str_repeat('-', $level).' '.$row['name_ro']."</option>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='".$row['section_id']."'>".str_repeat('-', $level).' '.$row['name_ro']."</option>\n";
        }

        generate_sections_select($row['section_id'], $level+1, $selected);
    }
}
```

Example:

- Level 1: Home page
- Level 2: About us
- Level 3: Our team

The absolute parent of "Our team" or "About us" is "Home page".

Comment: absolute parent will be the record that has no parent.

Comment: Yes, parent_id = 0, as I said, but how do I get it? :)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264158/create-treeview-looping-query/18264235#18264235). It seems to be very similar to what you're asking.

Comment: Tomas, it's not the same table layout and I can't change it.

Comment: Thomas' links has id and parent_id like your nodes so the logic is exactly the same. To alter it to fit your needs should be trivial.